# App created using kivymd force closes opening it in phone

Tags: python, kivymd

I built an app using kivymd I converted it to apk using the following commands . After installing it in my phone , while opening it it force closes within few seconds .

1.buildozer init

2.nano buildozer.spec
(In order to change some stuffs like app's name)

3.Then the following are some dependencies for buildozer

a)sudo apt update

b)sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev

c)pip3 install --user --upgrade Cython==0.29.19 virtualenv

d)export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/

After the above commands finally I execute the following command:

4.buildozer -v android debug

I use kivymd because it has good material design

I've added a picture below it loads like this and comes to my home screen again.

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: What does "it force closes in my phone after opening it"? Just as a meta-comment, that is an interpretation. However, it's more important that you describe the observation, i.e. what you see! Also, consider changing the title of your question, which doesn't give away anything at all about your actual problem.

Comment: Is it ok now . Can you find out the solution

Comment: It's still just an interpretation, I still don't know what you see!

Comment: Check out now. Can you find out

Comment: I still don't know what *you* mean with "it force closes". Describe what you see and *not* just what you think it means. Observation, not interpretation! BTW: Please take a look the numbering in your question. You have 1..3, then 1..4, then another 4.

Comment: Check out now Can you find out the issue

Answer (score 0):

One procedure you can do to get accurate information about the issue is, I guess your project has a "main.py" script, so make a copy of that script and rename it to, for example, "main2.txt", so it will be plain text (but it is your program), and then, edit the "main.py" script and insert the following code (watch my video https://youtu.be/LFQVhOzRlE0 ), please read the comments in the code:

```
try:
    m=open("main2.txt").read()
    exec(m)
except Exception as e:
    n=open("/storage/emulated/0/The_error_is_jbsidis.txt","w")
    #the path may be different from device to device,
    #sometimes is /sdcard/, for the app to have access
    #to the external storage in the mobile device you
    #should add the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
    #in the spec file, and then grant the permission manually
    #from the app manager from your cellphone,
    #this will help the apk, to be able to write content
    #to the device, then you can read it and see why the
    #app closes itself or what is throwing the error,
    #watch my video https://youtu.be/LFQVhOzRlE0
    #a fun fact is that if the "The_error_is_jbsidis.txt" file is empty (sometimes the app may crash before python can execute your main.py), that means that the issue is in the compilation itself or there is a missing module in your apk spec file #jbsidis
    n.write(str(e))
    n.close()
```

Remember to add the permissions in the spec file, otherwise the app will not have permission granted to read the storage of your device and won't be able to write the error before the app crashes, for more info watch my video: https://youtu.be/LFQVhOzRlE0

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) . I've actually moved from kivy to flutter framework for building apps:(

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Flutter is amazing, I'm sure you will do great projects using it, I have not used flutter because I'm not sure if I can use Flutter in the same way I can use kivy and python (my hardware does not have great capabilities), I highly recommend Python and Kivy because the speed for development is great but sometimes it throws errors and if there is not a right support then we can't just continue our project, maybe kivy is too young yet.

Comment: Yes , you said the correct issue . Even I faced many issues , I build apps in  a great way in kivy framework  the issue arises when I convert it to apk file . But here in Flutter you use apk file for building and debugging purpose . It's cool you won't face any issues . Even dart is a great language to learn . btw even I didn't use flutter cuz I didn't had a better hardware , now I'm having one :)