# Is there any fix for this crash lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+172)

Tags: python, android, crash, apk, buildozer

im trying to build my first apk with python + buildozer, while im running my apk on device it is crashed on loading screen:

```
from logcat:
08-21 14:36:21.220 10304 28953 28953 I crash_dump32: performing dump of process 15464 (target tid = 28945)
08-21 14:36:21.230 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-21 14:36:21.231 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/r9qxeea/r9q:11/RP1A.200720.012/G990BXXE1AUH5:eng/test-keys'
08-21 14:36:21.231 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   : Revision: '8'
08-21 14:36:21.231 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
08-21 14:36:21.232 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2021-08-21 14:36:21+0100
08-21 14:36:21.232 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   : pid: 15464, tid: 28945, name: SDLThread  >>> org.test.speedtestguionly <<<
08-21 14:36:21.233 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   : uid: 10304
08-21 14:36:21.233 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
08-21 14:36:21.233 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   :     r0  00000000  r1  00007111  r2  00000006  r3  c3c1bc40
08-21 14:36:21.233 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   :     r4  c3c1bc54  r5  c3c1bc38  r6  00003c68  r7  0000016b
08-21 14:36:21.233 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   :     r8  c3c1bc40  r9  c3c1bc50  r10 c3c1bc70  r11 c3c1bc60
08-21 14:36:21.233 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   :     ip  00007111  sp  c3c1bc10  lr  f52fc5dd  pc  f52fc5f0
08-21 14:36:21.236 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
08-21 14:36:21.236 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 000395f0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+172) (BuildId: 06e8cde30ce2feee4b53babf45fa4178)
08-21 14:36:21.236 10304 28953 28953 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 0016ad8c  /data/app/~~SFhjBn_FT7mxQhG17AycDA==/org.test.speedtestguionly-ww3SsbHrKMSlxZlq-5-6GQ==/lib/arm/libpython3.7m.so
08-21 14:36:21.459  1000   735   735 I io_stats: !@   8,0 r 272039 14297728 w 42925 538724 d 26974 105329728 f 0 0 iot 231220 0 th 0 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 537.633

08-21 14:36:23.701  1000  1012 28966 W ActivityManager: crash : org.test.speedtestguionly,10304
08-21 14:36:23.704  1000  1012 28966 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1162


buildozer spec: 
# (str) Title of your application
title = samoGUI

# (str) Package name
package.name = SpeedtestGUIonly

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3==3.7.10,kivy==2.0.0,speedtest-cli

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3.7.10

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.0.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions,
android.permissions = INTERNET,ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS,READ_PHONE_STATE,ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 30

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
android.sdk = 30

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 19c

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
# contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
# android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
#android.enable_androidx = False

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_packaging_options =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Android logcat only display log for activity's pid
#android.logcat_pid_only = False

# (str) Android additional adb arguments
#android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

# (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
# android.backup_rules =

# (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
# you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
# This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
# Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
# android.manifest_placeholders = [:]

# (bool) disables the compilation of py to pyc/pyo files when packaging
# android.no-compile-pyo = True

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android URL to use for checkout
#p4a.url =

# (str) python-for-android fork to use in case if p4a.url is not specified, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = Manaaa12

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) The development team to use for signing the debug version
#ios.codesign.development_team.debug = <hexstring>

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s

# (str) The development team to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.development_team.release = <hexstring>

# (str) URL pointing to .ipa file to be installed
# This option should be defined along with `display_image_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.app_url =

# (str) URL pointing to an icon (57x57px) to be displayed during download
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.display_image_url =

# (str) URL pointing to a large icon (512x512px) to be used by iTunes
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `display_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.full_size_image_url =


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

do you know how to fix it? i tried things with p4a=develop and other buildozer options like arch64, but i still got this error. first place i thought it is something with permissions, so i added the same as original speedtest is using.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question yesterday about this, we thank you for posting the logcat (most users here ask for that I don't know why), but here it could be a better method for you to see what is the real issue and solve it, it may be in your main.py or it maybe the buildozer installation, but if the builds completes and it generates an apk, buildozer and your PC is fine, and maybe is something in your main.py or just a missing script, I recommend you to watch my video about it: https://youtu.be/LFQVhOzRlE0 (the person yesterday said the answer was useless, but I guess that user did not even watch the video), if you want to take a look to that answer click here: [App created using kivymd force closes opening it in phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67488988/app-created-using-kivymd-force-closes-opening-it-in-phone/68869928#68869928)

I also recommend to watch the video: https://youtu.be/LFQVhOzRlE0

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer,i watched your video a few times,but i’m not sure if im doing it right: 1. I renamed my main.py to main2.txt 2. Edited my main.py to import os try: exec(open("/storage/emulated/0/Download/main2.txt").read()) except Exception as e: b=open("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Errors.txt","w") b.write(str(e)) b.close() 3.  storage/emulated/0/Download is the path on my phone where, main2.txt is located 4. i compiled the main.py to build .apk 5. installed apk and run it on my phone so after that i got apk crashed, but i cant find the Errors.txt file

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now that you have done everything, please, access to the settings in your phone, go to Application Manager (where you can uninstall, provide permissions, etc) and look for the app and provide the permission manually: Read External Storage or Access Storage Permission, because if the Errors.txt is not being created, it means the apk you have created has not gotten the permissions to write External or Internal Storage

Comment: In your buildozer ".spec" file make sure you have added the permissions needed: # (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET #SEND_SMS,RECORD_AUDIO, 
android.permissions = CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, VIBRATE, ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION, WAKE_LOCK, CAMERA, FLASHLIGHT,GLOBAL_SEARCH,BIND_PRINT_SERVICE,REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

Comment: Hello, i ve already done this before, i use the same permission as Speedtest is using and added some extra for read/write external storage and access media location, also i manually enabled them in App menager, still no errors.txt. tested on android 10 and 11.

Comment: Alright, thank you for providing more details about it, there are 3 options that I am guessing, the first one could be that the devices you are using they maynot save its content to /storage/emulated/0/ in most cases when Android versions are higher than 6, the internal or external storage maybe in /sdcard/ instead, the second there is really an error from the compilation and Python does not execute at all, then program a main script that executes the real script and if there is any error, just program to show that error as a MDLabel (this does not requires any permission)